# Suggestions for repairing a broken guitar tuning key

Tags: electric-guitar

I own a Cort KX5, which is an inexpensive beginners guitar. Being my first electric, love it to bits. Unfortunately, someone seems to have knocked it against my TV stand(which it normally stands next to) and broken the tuning key for the g string(present key condition pictured). [image: current key condition]
I was able to find a replacement on AliExpress, but this will take 30-40 days to arrive and none of the stores around me (in Bangalore,India) seem to carry the same key type, a replacement would require me to drill holes for the holding screws(I'm keen to not alter the guitar physically). Does anyone know of a way I can repair the broken key so that I can use it until the replacements arrive?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine there's a screw in the end of the part that's broken off. take it out, and find a longer screw that will go into the hollow of the other part. It needs to be a good fit, without exploding the bigger part. Use epoxy resin (two-part adhesive) making sure it goes into both holes. Screw the replacement screw in, but be careful to scrape off any that would bond the turning part to the rest. If that does the trick, I'd put the B string machine head where the G was, and use the mended one in the middle of three. Then invest in either a stand, or a wall hanger - and use it!